# Redirect policy in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Does Azure API Management (Azure APIM) provide any way to redirect urls, in order to replicate [Apigee RedirectToLoginPage](https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/oauth-login-app) functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this isn't supported at Azure APIM level. Since I was using IdentityServer for Oauth2 security, I accomplished this by writing an owin/katana authentication middleware. Anders Abel has a great [post about it](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/writing-an-owin-authentication-middleware/).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a policy set at the global (All APIs) scope.

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(!context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.Contains("redirect.com"))">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="303" reason="See Other" />
            <set-header name="Location" exists-action="override">
                <value>@("https://redirect.com/" + context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path + context.Request.OriginalUrl.QueryString)</value>
            </set-header>
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>
```